Real-time Audio Streaming Not Playing on iOS with WebSocket and Audio APIs
I'm building a real-time audio streaming app using WebSocket and audio APIs, but I'm facing issues specifically on iOS. The app streams audio chunks received via WebSocket from the ElevenLabs API and plays them sequentially. It works fine on most platforms, but on iOS, the audio either doesn't play or is delayed.
What I've Tried:

Using Web Audio API: I attempted to play the audio chunks directly using AudioContext, but iOS had compatibility issues with real-time streaming.
Converting to Blob: I converted the received audio chunks to a Blob and used an  element to play them. This worked, but it introduced significant delays between consecutive chunks, which is not acceptable for real-time streaming.

let connectButton = null;
let disconnectButton = null;
let sendButton = null;
let receiveBox = null;
let inputText = null;
let audioPlayer = document.getElementById("audioPlayer");

let ws = null;
let audioQueue = []; 
let isPlaying = false; 

const ELEVENLABS_WS_URL = "wss://api.elevenlabs.io/v1/text-to-speech/XrExE9yKIg1WjnnlVkGX/stream-input?model_id=eleven_multilingual_v1&inactivity_timeout=30&language=English_American";

function startup() {
    connectButton = document.getElementById("connectButton");
    disconnectButton = document.getElementById("disconnectButton");
    sendButton = document.getElementById("sendButton");
    receiveBox = document.getElementById("receive-box");
    inputText = document.getElementById("inputText");
    audioPlayer = document.getElementById("audioPlayer");

    connectButton.addEventListener("click", initializeWebSocket, false);
    disconnectButton.addEventListener("click", closeWebSocket, false);
    sendButton.addEventListener("click", sendMessage, false);
}

function initializeWebSocket() {
    if (!ws || ws.readyState === WebSocket.CLOSED) {        
        ws = new WebSocket(ELEVENLABS_WS_URL);

        ws.onopen = () => {
            console.log("Connected to ElevenLabs WebSocket.");
            connectButton.disabled = true;
            disconnectButton.disabled = false;
        };

        ws.onmessage = handleWebSocketMessage;
        ws.onerror = (error) => console.error("WebSocket error:", error);
        ws.onclose = () => {
            console.log("Disconnected from ElevenLabs WebSocket.");
            connectButton.disabled = false;
            disconnectButton.disabled = true;
        };
    }
}

function closeWebSocket() {
    if (ws) {
        ws.close();
        console.log("WebSocket connection closed.");
    }
}

function sendMessage() {
    const text = inputText.value.trim();
    if (text) {
        const message = {
            text: text,
            voice_settings: {
                stability: 1,
                similarity_boost: true,
                optimize_streaming_latency: 0
            },
            flush: true,
            xi_api_key: "",
            streaming: true
        };

        if (ws && ws.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
            ws.send(JSON.stringify(message));
        } else {
            console.error("WebSocket is not connected.");
        }
    }
}

function handleWebSocketMessage(event) {
    const audioData = JSON.parse(event.data);
    console.log('audioData: ', typeof audioData);
    
    if (audioData && audioData.audio) {
        const base64Audio = audioData.audio;
        addAudioChunkToQueue(base64Audio);
    } else {
        console.error("No audio data received.");
    }
}

function addAudioChunkToQueue(base64Audio) {
    const audioBuffer = base64ToArrayBuffer(base64Audio);
    audioQueue.push(audioBuffer);

    if (!isPlaying) {
        playNextChunk();
    }
}

function playNextChunk() {
    if (audioQueue.length > 0) {
        isPlaying = true;
        const audioBuffer = audioQueue.shift();

        const audioBlob = new Blob([audioBuffer], { type: 'audio/mpeg' });
        const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);
        audioPlayer.src = audioUrl;
        audioPlayer.play()
            .then(() => {
                console.log("Playing audio chunk...");
                audioPlayer.onended = () => {
                    isPlaying = false;
                    playNextChunk(); 
                };
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error("Error playing audio:", error);
                isPlaying = false;
            });
    } else {
        isPlaying = false;
    }
}

function base64ToArrayBuffer(base64) {
    console.log('Converting to arraybuffer');
    const binaryString = window.atob(base64);
    const len = binaryString.length;
    const bytes = new Uint8Array(len);
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        bytes[i] = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return bytes.buffer;
}
`
window.addEventListener("load", startup);```


Ideal Solution (use HTTP GET, not Web Socket)
In the ideal case, you don't use Web Socket... you use a normal HTTP GET request.  Does your provider not offer it?  If they do, you can use a normal audio element...
const audio = new Audio('https://speech-api.example.com/some-stream');
audio.play();

If you find that your playback buffer is getting behind, you can drift it forward.
audio.playbackRate = 1.05


Non-Ideal Solution (stuck with Web Sockets)
If you're stuck with Web Sockets, then you must also decode the audio to PCM yourself.  In other words, you need to implement MP3 client-side.
The good news is that MP3 patents have expired and that you can use Emscripten to build an existing codec (such as MPG123) for Web Assembly.
You need to decode the stream of MPEG frames to 32-bit float PCM.  This is different than using audioContext.decodeAudioData(), because the audio context is intending to decode an entire standalone file.  MP3 cannot be cleanly spliced on its own.  The decoded standalone file will have padding.
Next, you need to playback these chunks of PCM.  You cannot do this simply by loading them into AudioContext's AudioBuffer instances and then play them one after the other.  It's literally impossible to get the timing right.  What you need to do instead is have something that generates a stream of audio.  You can use either ScriptProcessorNode or its equivalent AudioWorklet.  Then, in each loop of the process, chop off a chunk of your previously buffered PCM and send it as a fresh buffer back to AudioContext.  The AudioContext will then handle buffering it to the underlying audio system, ensuring sample-accurate gapless playback.
In the future, the WebCodecs API will make some of these things easier, but it isn't compatible yet, and the core principles will still be there.
